# glutInit parameters in simple OSX example

Tags: macos, opengl, arguments, glut

I'm working with an [example from this site](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/teaching/Interactive3D/2011/compiling.html) on OSX and I have no troubles compiling it but I don't know how to test run it. The program looks like this:

```
void display()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutMainLoop();
}
```

I don't know what the arguments should be for the program, which `glutInit` will use. Does anybody know what with which arguments I need to call me program to acually show a window?

Calling with no arguments orcourse causes this crash:

```
./hello 
2011-10-13 11:41:15.360 hello[2395:903] GLUT Fatal API Usage: main loop entered with no windows created.
Abort trap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a GLUT window before calling glutDisplayFunc or glutMainLoop

Comment: I am stuck with this error. How did you get rid of this error? Please help me understand.

Comment: Call `glutCreateWindow` before anything that's named `glut…Func` or `glutMainLoop` *but* after `glutInitDisplayMode` which in turn must be called after `glutInit`.